# Velocity of object on extremely low air density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag, equations-of-motion

If we derive velocity in air when setting air resistance to $kv$,
we'll get 
$$v= \frac{mg}{k}\left(1-e^{\frac{kt}{m}}\right) $$
and if air density goes to $0$, $k$ will also goes to $0$.

When $t=T$ (certain number), $ \lim_{k\to 0}v=gT $. This matches my expectation. 
However, if we graph $v(k, t=T)$ with respect to $k$, it seems diverges near $0$.

Why this happens and Does that represent reality? Which tells velocity of object at certain time keeps increase to infinity until the air density finally hit $0$ and then velocity becomes certain finite number? 
If it's not, which part of the arguments develops such error mathematically?

*I started with $\frac{dv}{dt}=g-\frac{kv}{m}$ and integrated LHS with $dv$ and RHS with $dt$.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity(speed) does not diverge as far as I can see.

I think you are having some problem in taking the small k limit.

Using the Taylor expansion for the exponential we can write
$$ v = \frac{mg}{k}(1 - (1 + \frac{kt}{m} + \frac{1}{2!}(\frac{kt}{m})^2 + \ldots)) $$
where I have suppressed the higher order terms as we are interested in the limit where $k \to 0$. Then the equation simplifies to
$$ v = -gt - \frac{gkt^2}{2m} + \ldots $$
which does not have divergence as you can see.

Note: Also the negative sign in the final result makes me think that there supposed to negative sign in the exponential to start with.